# Cache Evict Verification

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I use Redis as a cache store in spring boot using @Cachable annotation and evict it programitically using:

```
cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).clear()
```

The eviction process works fine. I need to add additional check after eviction that if cache entries still exist, and then perform some alert operation. For that, I need to get the Cache, check # of entries etc. I am trying the following way, but unable to retrieve anything:

```
cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).getNativeCache()
```

Is there any way to check if that Cache (Redis Cache) is a valid Cache and can contain keys/values.

Comment: Native cache returns the underlying implementation of the cache. You could just inject the RedisTemplate and use it query the spring cache key to check its empty

Comment: I don't have cacheKey. I clear whole cacheName. I tried redisTemplate but it's not giving me anything. If possible, kindly share a code sample to pull/check data out of CacheName.

Answer (score 0):

```
cacheManager.getCacheNames()
```

This returns all the caches present at the moment.
You can check if your evicted cache is present anymore or not and then perform alert operation.